# Ubuntu and Fedora dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader, fedora

I've successfully dual-booted Fedora and Ubuntu. How do I remove the bootloader from Fedora and just use Ubuntu's bootloader for both Fedora and Ubuntu?
(Ubuntu version 14.01 and Fedora 21 )

Comment: Boot ubuntu, install grub - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows . IMO best to chainload http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2260361

Answer (score 2):

from ubuntu

```
sudo grub-install /dev/XXX
sudo update-grub
```

where XXX is the drive with the mbr you need to overwrite like sda or sdb